# How to provide free connection with usage caps (dd-wrt firmware)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I've got a pretty badass router (okay, not that good, but not bad: TP_link TR1034ND), with DD-WRT firmware. My connection is about 90/35mbps which is also pretty good.

I want to provide a free access point with limited bandwidth. The range is really huge so anyone could use it even on the street and I'm fine with that. But I don't want everyone to download their porn from my wifi every day from the street. I don't want to bandwidth limit them.. so let's say they can use 1gb, BUT speed limit them. They can sleep before my house if they want, I don't care... but don't make my connection slow/useless. :)

So.. how could I do this? Basically, I need a public network, with usage caps.

Comment: Did you mean WR1034ND? http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?class=wlan&pmodel=TL-WR1043ND

Comment: Oh..thats it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DD-WRT has built in options for configuring hotspots.  There are three that I know of:

1.[Chillispot](http://www.chillispot.info/)

> - Easily make the wireless or lan-connected computers display a 'landing page' on user's browsers.
> - Redirection occurs on the first web page, and until the user clicks through (I Agree/Login).
> - Optionally earn revenue from your hotspot.
> - Provide a WiFi usage agreement, advertising or other neighbourhood or commercial activities.
> - Pro-active over-use prevention:
> - Limit the bandwidth, up and down, hotspot-connected laptops or desktops can use.
> - Limit the number of times within a given period hotspot users can log in.
> - Other fine-grained limitations.
> - ChilliSpot can be used for single router, or extended with the use of external services to cover an entire metropolitan area.

2.[Anchor Free](http://www.anchorfree.com/)

> Which is similar to Chillispot but is advertising based.

3.[SputnikNet](http://www.sputnik.com/)

> SputnikNet is the super-flexible, web-based management and captive portal authentication system for Wi-Fi hotspots and hotzones. Manage one or thousands of hotspots with SputnikNet. SputnikNet enables you to:
>
> - auto-provision Wi-Fi access points (APs) by plugging them into broadband
> - manage Wi-Fi APs centrally, over a secure Web connection
> - design captive portals with your brand
> - authenticate users and devices for free or paid Wi-Fi
> - track usage by access point and Wi-Fi end user

Each of these are already installed on the DD-WRT flashed device.  Setup is pretty easy, and here are the guides:

- [Chillispot](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot)
- [AnchorFree](http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/dd-wrt-repeater-bridge-two-ssid-using-anchorfree-wireless)
- [SputnikNet](http://docs.sputnik.com/manuals/agent/lessons/4042)

Comment: Yeah I saw these but it looks like these are ... paid stuff. But thank you, I'll have a look at them.

Comment: To my understanding and knowledge they aren't.  But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can also give [Tomato firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29) a thought as it has some features which might help you. We are using the Toastman build and it has exactly what you require w/o any complicated configurations or Qos settings as needed in DD-WRT:

**Access Restriction Overview**

You can restrict access to your AP by IP/MAC and even assign the timings/days for restriction. For example, you can allow your trusted IPs to bypass this limit and rest can enjoy the free internet for a set time period or just Sundays!

**Bandwidth Limiter - QOS**

You can define your own trusted IP Ranges/MAC ids to bypass this limit while rest of the people accessing your AP will be restricted.

There is also a Captive Portal Management so your guests can see your banner or something when accessing.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service) for a QoS article with ddwrt, you will want to do it by IP address. Provide public access to a specific IP range and then apply QoS to that range.

Comment: And how can I make a new wifi network only for these freeloaders?

Comment: Not another network, but another range. You would need to specify two cidr ranges for the LAN interface, one you can do DHCP to publicly hand out addresses, the other you can set to statically assign to your own network devices. Anyone who is not authorized (statically set), gets put on the public DHCP range that has QoS and limits all the main bandwidth clogging apps.